# Magnetised Torus, where are its poles?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have been thinking about this  recently but have found no good solution so I thought I might post it here to see what other people think:

Consider a cylinder made of iron that is magnetised so that the two poles are on the two opposite circular ends. Now suppose we bend this magnet. Bending the magnet does not change where the poles are ( alternate: or consider a bent version of the cylinder magnetised with the two poles on opposite circular ends ).

Suppose we bend this magnet into a torus, so that the north/south poles are brought into direct contact with each other (as they are opposite they should attract so repulsion is not a problem here) to form a torus. (alternate: or consider a series of progressively more bent cylinders whose limit is the torus).

What I can't seem to figure out is where would the North/South poles of this  magnet be or even whether the torus would have a magnetic field!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's basically a ring of magnetic dipoles, so far away the field would be very weak: the magnetic dipole from one side of the ring is opposite to the magnetic dipole on the other side of the ring, so the fields they generate tend to cancel. The total magnetic dipole moment would be 0, so no poles (which are a convenient fiction for magnetism in any case - at least classically).

Comment: The "duplicate" question considers magnetic dipoles arranged on a torus so that they point in a radial direction . This question considers dipoles arranged so that they point in a tangential direction. I don't think it's a duplicate, at least not a duplicate of the indicated question.